# Redirect a subsite in an Azure web app to a different site

Tags: azure, web, url, azure-web-app-service

An Azure web app has several subsites/virtual paths:

- `azure-web-app.com/subsite1`
- `azure-web-app.com/subsite2`
- `azure-web-app.com/subsite3`

Is it possible to configure the site such that when `azure-web-app.com/subsite3` is accessed by the user in the browser, it automatically redirects to `completely-different-site.com`?

I have not tested potential solutions I have read about because there is only a prod instance of the site (no dev - I know that is not a best practice) and it would be helpful to know where to head before proceeding.

Other info:

- The site has a custom domain applied - e.g., `azure-web-app.com`.
- Stack is .NET v4.7

I can provide any missing details. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wanna redirect `azure-web-app.com/subsite3` to `completely-different-site.com`, it will help you. You could refer to the code as below:

```
<rewrite>  
    <rules>  
        <rule name="Redirect subsite to different url" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(^subsite3)(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://completely-different-site.com/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
        </rule> 
    </rules>  
</rewrite>
```